# Spock @Unroll annotation

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, spock

During a recent code review, the question came up regarding whether the @Unroll annotation belongs at the class level or the method level. The class in question requires @Unroll on most of its methods but not all of them. Does declaring @Unroll incur any performance penalties if declared at the class level and not all methods of the class require it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The @Unroll annotation is intended to be used on the method level. But it can also be used on the class level as indicated in the [Unroll.java JavaDoc comments](https://github.com/spockframework/spock/blob/07c2d477563ccb40dde6a7f701a2056ebe4c10e1/spock-core/src/main/java/spock/lang/Unroll.java#L38-L41):

> The {@code Unroll} annotation can also be put on a spec class. This has the same effect as putting it on every data-driven feature method that is not already annotated with {@code Unroll}. By embedding the naming pattern in the method names, each method can still have its own pattern.