# What is the purpose of Spock's @Unroll annotation

Tags: spock

I'm having difficulties in understanding the `@Unroll` annotation of Spock's testing framework. In the docs, it is mentioned

> Indicates that iterations of a data-driven feature should be made visible
>    as separate features to the outside world (IDEs, reports, etc.)

Still makes not much sense to me. Could someone explain in layman's terms?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spock @Unroll annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30577376/spock-unroll-annotation)

Comment: Sorry for being so blunt, but please be so kind as to [RTFM](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.1/all_in_one.html#_method_unrolling). Thank you very much.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`@Unroll` is to have each data driven iterations reported independently, as indicated in [Spock's website](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.1/data_driven_testing.html).
I want to add for some more information on using `@Unroll`.

---

If you are using `@Unroll` please also customize your test name, it will help you with your reports, example:

```
@Unroll
  def "maximum of #a and #b is #c"() { ... }
```

When using the `@Unroll` each data driven iteration will be counted as a "test" that means that your test count will increase.

Use `@Unroll` if you have data driven tests.

Answer (score 3):

Awesome description is at the [Spock's website](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.0/data_driven_testing.html). I should have looked at it in the first place (second place actually, after doc). The main feature is, in case of a failure, the reporting will indicate with what exactly test data it failed, leaving aside the other cases.

> an alternation in reporting
>
> the output will look something like

```
maximum of two numbers[0]   PASSED
maximum of two numbers[1]   FAILED

Math.max(a, b) == c
    |    |  |  |  |
    |    7  0  |  7
    42         false

maximum of two numbers[2]   PASSED
```